# Can LEGO Boost play custom audio files?

Tags: boost

Can LEGO Boost play custom audio files on the Boost app from files kept on the device such as those downloaded from iTunes or transferred from a computer?

Are recordings from the tablet the only way to use custom sounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, recordings from the tablet are the only way to use custom sounds at the moment. I imagine that the UI for a feature like this was deemed too complex for an app designed for children under 12. However, this should be easy to add to the app in a future update if there is demand for it.

One obvious workaround for this is to play the desired sound on another device and save it using the recording interface:

[image: recording interface]

These recordings are limited to about 5 seconds.